# I want to create navbar as shown in the link. I want it to show on scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not able to find or think how this navbar is made. How to add navlist on Video and on scroll make navbar visible. Is there any way, article or any hint to get started with this.
LINK - https://susodigital.com/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add a `scroll` event listener to `window`. Inside, if `window.scrollY > 0`, you add the CSS class that changes the navbar style (and probably makes its position fixed as well). If `window.scrollY === 0`, remove that CSS class.

Just remember to run that check one time at the start of the code too so that the class is added/removed when the user refreshes.